# VRF Internet Gateway Multiple External IP's 1 Internal IP to AWS

Tags: vpn, cisco, amazon-web-services

Trying to setup VRF for the first time and its not working for me even though I keep reading everything online.

IP's are different to real life.

I have an Internet connection which I can ping to my router in the current setup below 195.45.73.22

I have a block of ip addresses 195.45.121.0/27

I want to setup multiple VPN's to AWS so need to have multiple external ip's thus the block of IP addresses.

I have setup the 2nd and 3rd IP address but can not ping them from external.

Any help would be grateful.

Bryan

ip source-route
!

ip vrf Internet

rd 1:1

route-target export 1:1

route-target import 1:1

ip vrf AWSSydney1

rd 2:2

route-target export 2:2

route-target import 2:2

route-target import 1:1

ip vrf AWSSydney2

rd 3:3

route-target export 3:3

route-target import 3:3

route-target import 1:1

ip cef

no ip domain lookup

no ipv6 cef

multilink bundle-name authenticated

interface FastEthernet0/0

description Vocus Internet

no ip address

speed 100

full-duplex

interface FastEthernet0/0.1

encapsulation dot1Q 1 native

ip address 195.45.73.22 255.255.255.252

interface FastEthernet0/0.2

encapsulation dot1Q 2

ip vrf forwarding AWSSydney1

ip address 195.45.121.1 255.255.255.224

interface FastEthernet0/0.3

encapsulation dot1Q 3

ip vrf forwarding AWSSydney2

ip address 195.45.121.2 255.255.255.224

interface FastEthernet0/1

description LAN_SIDE

ip address 10.0.0.5 255.255.255.0

speed 100

full-duplex

no mop enabled

ip forward-protocol nd

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 195.45.73.21

ip route vrf Internet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 195.45.73.21

Answer (score 0):

You need necessary routes in VRFs. Use show ip route vrf to check if all required routes existed in the VRF. You may need to *leak* some routes from the main routing table to the VRF.